# Как фставить Multipartfile в обычный json обьект RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, multipartfile

Мне необходимо в запросе с postman отправить requestbody, но внутрь в поле photo надо засунуть изображение - multipartfile, как это делается?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно бинарные данные в base64 загнать.

Comment: Или использовать режим form-data в Postman'е.

Comment: еще бы понимать как это сделать - бинарные данные загнать в base64, как закодировать-раскодировать я заню, а вот с бинарными дела не имел и пока ничего толкового не нашел по тематике

Comment: Возможно, будет полезно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Вот так сработало норм, обязательно пришлось проставить content-type в requestbody - form-data[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Использовать wildcard в ResponseEntity - плохая идея, возвращайте конкретный тип

Answer (score 0):

А если вам надо чтобы postman отправлял единый requestBody - тогда этот вариант лучше[image: введите сюда описание изображения]